# Limit of a system of nonhomogeneous ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, upper-lower-bounds, homogeneous-equation

I have a system of ordinary differential equations with the following structure,
$$ y'(t) = A(\lambda) y(t) + \lambda b(t), \qquad y(t)\geq 0, \> b(t)\geq 0 $$
Here the $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$ depends on some parameter $\lambda > 0$. I want to estimate $\lambda_{c}$ s.t. if $\lambda < \lambda_{c}$,  $\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t) = 0 $.
I know $b_{1}=b_{2}=0$ and $b_{3}$, $b_{4}$ can be bounded in terms of $y_{1}$ or $y_{2}$.
Would transforming the system into
$$ y'(t) = \tilde A(\lambda) y(t) + \lambda \tilde b(t) \> \text{where} \> y(t)\geq 0, \> \tilde b(t)\leq 0 $$
Be sufficient to conclude that if $\tilde A(\lambda)$ has all negative eigenvalues, $\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t) = 0 $?
If this is the case, would making $|\tilde b(t)|$ smaller make my estimate for $\lambda_{c}$ better?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Assuming that $b(t)$ is Laplace transformable, first, be sure that the eigenvalues for $A(\lambda)$ are non-positive and after that use the Laplace final value theorem. With null initial conditions we have

$$
\lim_{s\to 0}s\lambda \left(I s-A(\lambda)\right)^{-1}B(s) = y_{\infty}
$$